# Excel summing number of rows over range that adheres to multiple criteria

Tags: excel, colors, excel-formula, array-formulas

I'm looking for a way to count how many rows in my range (that runs over two columns) adhere to the criteria that one one cell in the row has a specific background color whilst the other cell in the same row has a different specific background color.

As things stand, I have tried using colorfunction inside Countifs but they appear to be giving the wrong answer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart...
For check with two color, for my function you have:

```
Public Function CountColor(Sel As Range, Col As Long, Col1 As Long) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    Dim i As Long

    i = 0
    For Each xx In Sel
        If (xx.Interior.Color = Col) And (xx.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = Col1) Then i = i + 1
    Next
    CountColor = i
End Function
```

If you want to refer to a cell with the color:

```
Public Function CountColorR(Sel As Range, ColR As Range, ColR1 As Range) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    Dim i, Col, Col1 As Long

    Col = ColR.Interior.Color
    Col1 = ColR1.Interior.Color
    i = 0
    For Each xx In Sel
        If (xx.Interior.Color = Col) And (xx.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = Col1) Then i = i + 1
    Next
    CountColorR = i
End Function
```

In your function you need to add the if (...) and (...) part of code plus the part of the color...
In your function I don't understand the part with SUM/Count ...

Answer (score 1):

Directly with EXCEL Function, I think it's impossibile because you don't have a function that return the Inner Color.
Using VBA (Inside a Module):

```
Public Function CountColor(Sel As Range, Col As Long) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    i = 0
    For Each xx In Sel
        If xx.Interior.Color = Col Then i = i + 1
    Next
    CountColor = i
End Function
```

You need to know the color... Use the function:

```
Public Function InnerColor(Sel As Range) As Long
    InnerColor = Sel.Interior.Color
End Function
```

Using NAMES: Define Names -> Color:

```
=GET.CELL(63;OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC";FALSE);0;-1))
```

you can have an indirect reference. Don't work with Countif. In a case like:

[image]

with the name define before, you can create a column with:

```
=IF(color>0;1;0)
```

and a simple:

```
=SUM(K5:K16)
```

to have the yellow cells number.
Don't work immediately (also VBA) if you don't make a recalculate (F9)...

Comment: I thought the colorfunction() in excel 2007 was able to tell you if the fill colour of a cell in a range matched that of a specified target cell. For example, colorfunction(A1, B1:B100, false) will count how many cells in the range B1:B100 have a fill colour that matches that of cell A1?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I feel as if you're missing the point of the question. Using the colorfunction() as described above, I can do exactly what you've listed in the answer. What I need is to count how many rows in a range of TWO columns contain cells that a both shaded, for example, where one cell in column 1 is blue and the other in column 2 is red.

Comment: I don't found the function you write... It's not a standard... In any case, it's ok VBA or not ? If yes, it's simple to modify the VBA already write...

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)

Dim rCell As Range

Dim lCol As Long

Dim vResult



lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex



    If Count = True Then

       For Each rCell In rRange

        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then

                vResult = WorksheetFunction.Count(rCell) + vResult

        End If

       Next rCell

    Else

        For Each rCell In rRange

        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then

                vResult = 1 + vResult

        End If

       Next rCell

End If



ColorFunction = vResult

End Function
```